# How to use Ambari service to deploy a jar on all hadoop nodes?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have a requirement where I want to deploy a jar file at a particular location on all hadoop cluster nodes using Ambari server. For that purpose I think I can use service feature.
So I created a sample service and could deploy it as client or slave on all nodes.
I added a new folder as Testservice inside /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/ and it has following files/directories

```
[machine]# cd /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/Testservice^C
[machine]#
[machine]# pwd
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/Testservice
[machine]# ls
configuration  metainfo.xml  package
[machine]# ls package/*
package/archive.zip

package/files:
filesmaster.py  test1.jar

package/scripts:
test_client.py
[machine]#
```

With this my service is added and installed on all nodes. On each node, a respective directory "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/Testservice" is created with same file structure as mentioned above.  As of now test_client.py script has no code at all. Just dummy implementation of  install, configure function.

So here I want to add code such that package/files/test1.jar from each host to a defined destination location  say "/lib folder. 
I need help on this point. How I can make use test_client.py script?  How I can write generic code to copy my jar file.

test_client.py has install method as shown below

```
class TestClient(Script):
def install(self, env):
```

Need more details how env variable can be used to get all required base paths for ambari service directory and hadoop install base paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that you can use a Custom Ambari Service to ensure a file is present on various nodes in your cluster. Your custom service should have a CLIENT component which handles laying down the files you need on various hosts in the cluster. It should be a client component because it has no running processes.

However, using the files folder is not the correct approach to distribute the file you have (test1.jar). All the Ambari services rely on linux packages to install the necessary files on the system. So what you should be doing is creating a software package that takes care of laying down that lib file to the correct location on disk. This could be an rpm and/or deb file depending on what OSs you are planning to support. Once you have the software package you can accomplish your goal by modifying two files you already have outlined above.

**metainfo.xml** - You will list the necessary software packages required for your service to function correctly. For example if you were planning on supporting RHEL6 and RHEL7 you would create an rpm package named my_package_name and include it with this code:

```
 <osSpecifics>
   <osSpecific>
     <osFamily>redhat6,redhat7</osFamily>
       <packages>
         <package>
           <name>my_package_name</name>
         </package>
        </packages>
    </osSpecific>
 </osSpecifics>
```

**test-client.py** - You will need to replace the starter code you have in your question with:

```
 class TestClient(Script):
   def install(self, env):
     self.install_packages(env)
```

The self.install_packages(env) call will ensure that the packages you have listed in metainfo.xml file get installed when your custom service CLIENT component is installed.

Note: Your software package (rpm, deb, etc.) will have to be hosted in an online repository in order for Ambari to access it and install it. You could create a local repository on the node running Ambari Server using httpd and createrepo. This process can be gleaned from the [HDP Documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_setting_up_a_local_repository.html).

**Alternative approach (Not Recommended)**

Now that I have explained the way it **SHOULD** be done. Let me tell you how you can achieve this using the package/files folder. Again this is not the recommended approach to handle installing software on a linux system, the package management system for your distribution should be handling this.

**test-client.py** - Update your starter file to include the below content. For this example we will copy your test1.jar to /lib folder with file permissions 0664, owner of 'guest', and group 'hadoop':

```
 def configure(self,env):
   File("/lib/test1.jar",
    mode=0644,
    group="hadoop",
    owner="guest",
    content=StaticFile("test1.jar")
    )
```

*Why is this approach not recommended?* This is not recommended because installing software on a linux distribution should be managed so that it makes it easy to upgrade and remove said software. Ambari does not have full uninstall functionality when it comes to its services. The most you can do is remove a service from being managed in your ambari cluster, after doing so all those files will remain on the system and would have to be removed by writing a custom script or doing it manually. However if you used package managment to handle installing the files you could easily remove the software by using the same package management system.

Comment: Can you not, theoretically, package an archive and use the install method to call Execute() and extract and copy the contents? What are the arguments against doing that?

Comment: @JeroenVlek, I've updated my answer to provide an alternative and also explained why my original answer is the best/industry standard approach.

Comment: @Jackson I have already tried second option i.e. using File function and for now it has worked for me. However I was not aware of standard package approach. So thanks for sharing details on that. I will try that also to see how it works.

Comment: If either option worked please accept the answer. Thanks.